# Windows Termin new tab and command

Tags: command-line, terminal, batch, cmd.exe, windows-terminal

I'm trying to open a new tab in Windows terminal and execute a command after that.

I've got this:

```
wt -w 0 nt -d . cmd /k cd "D:\Minecraft\Waterfall Network\Waterfall Network - 01 - Proxy" && start /b start_proxy.bat
```

So far it opens a new tab and accurately changes the path just like given via cd but does not execute the .bat afterwards.
Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current CMD window steals the `&& start /b start_proxy.bat` instead of passing it to the new tab.

You can fix by escaping the ampersand characters with `^`:

```
wt -w 0 nt -d . cmd /k cd "D:\Minecraft\Waterfall Network\Waterfall Network - 01 - Proxy" ^&^& start /b start_proxy.bat
```

---

You might prefer using the `-d|--startingDirectory` parameter for WT, but it's personal preference:

```
wt -w 0 nt -d "D:\Minecraft\Waterfall Network\Waterfall Network - 01 - Proxy" cmd /k start_proxy.bat
```